# "video recording stopped the maximum length for this video has been reached" Xcode iPhone

Tags: video, uiimagepickercontroller, duration

I am working on iPhone Video Capturing using ImagePickerController.I have set the property for image picker controller.I used it to have a maximum length of video to be 60 seconds.

```
imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration=60;
```

I am geting a default alert:

> "video recording stopped the maximum length for this video has been reached"

I don't want to see this alert when time reaches 60 seconds, how can I make it not appear?

Answer (score 0):

as apple states:

"The default value for this property is 10 minutes (600 seconds)"

so use:

```
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.sourceType = .camera
    picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
    picker.videoQuality = .typeMedium // .typeHigh
    picker.videoMaximumDuration = 20 * 60  // is in secs., here 20 minutes
```